# '__doPostBack' OR '.click()' Which is better?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using javascript in my ASP.Net web appliction. I am using `__doPostBack` and `.click()` event for calling server-side methods or code behind methods as shown below.

```
<input id="btnBindGridTrigger" runat="server" type="button" style="display:none" onserverclick="btnBindGridTrigger_Click" />
```

```js
function tabClickEnt() {
    __doPostBack('btnBindGridTrigger', '');
    document.getElementById('btnBindGridTrigger').click();
    // both is working fine but which is better and what id diffrence between above both ?
}
```

```cs
protected void btnBindGridTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindGrid();
    // other stuff
}
```

The above code working perfectly. Either I used `__doPostBack`  OR `.click()` in js function both will work and both methods call the server side event `btnBindGridTrigger_Click`.

But, I want to know the difference between both and which is better as performance view.

Please give me suggestions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Click eventually calls `__doPostBack` so from the performance point of view, this is one less function call.

**But**

`__doPostBack` is not documented so it may change or even be removed from any future versions which leads to broken code and/or runtime errors.

This is a common problem when using the "Internal Use" or "Infrastructure" methods, documented or not. The author gives no guarantee that such methods will always act same as the way they do now.

So don't use `__doPostBack`. Always try the click or other higher-level methods and let ASP.NET do its job, either by using `__doPostBack` or any other means it sees fit.

Comment: can you provide any link or article regarding this ? will helps lot

Comment: This was just my experience, but sure. I will find something for you